# how to design mongodb based product schema, some data fields could link to different lanuage

Tags: mongodb, schema

I am design a product schema in mongodb - mongoose, the schema is simply like

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name:String,         
        description:String, 
        img:String,  
    });
```

However, in this schema, I need to name the product in Both french and english, how could I make the this flexible to different language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've seen a similar example that where the names are stored like this:

```
> db.dogs.insert( { name: { de: 'Hund',
                            en: 'dog',
                            es: 'perro',
                            fr: 'chien' }
                  } )
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.dogs.find( {}, { "name.en": 1 })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54472399e3ce503b652f4790"), "name" : { "en" : "dog" } }
```